# Fill an array using twitter API

Tags: php, html, api, twitter

For one of my courses, I have to create a website where I can compare Twitter accounts (French Youtubers) according to some criteria as `followers_count`, `statuses_count`, or the most popular tweet of the people I choose.

My 3 API requests all work.
To make this comparison, I created a table, and now I want to put each request in the right cell.
How can I do that?

This is my table. I put random numbers in for the moment. The first value is the name of the Youtuber and the second, the gender. They never change. The 2
numbers are the answer at $tweets->followers_count ; and $tweets->statuses_count ; . This is where I want to put my API request.

"Meilleur Tweet" must show the best tweet of the Youtuber since the 7 last days.

```
$max_retweets = -1;

$best_tweets = null;

foreach ($tweets as $key => $object) {
    $retweet_current = $object->retweet_count;
    $tweet_current = $object->text;
    if ($retweet_current > $max_retweets){
        $max_retweets = $retweet_current;
        $best_tweets = $tweet_current;
    }
}

echo ($best_tweets);

 echo ($best_tweets);
```

Here is the array I want to use :

```
$tableau = [["","Squeezie", "homme", 748, 394, "meilleur_tweeet", "gaming", "voir_plus"],
    ["","Cyprien", "homme", 87, 459, "meilleur_tweeet", "humour", "voir_plus"],
    ["","Amixem", "homme", 87, 459, "meilleur_tweeet", "humour", "voir_plus"],
    ["","Natoo", "femme", 17, 4594, "meilleur_tweeet", "humour", "voir_plus"],
    ["","Norman", "homme", 87, 459, "meilleur_tweeet", "humour", "voir_plus"],
    ["","Tibo Inshape", "homme", 65, 459, "meilleur_tweeet", "humour", "voir_plus"],
    ["","Rémi Gaillard", "homme", 87, 459, "meilleur_tweeet", "humour", "voir_plus"],;
```

Comment: What is `$tweets`?

Comment: _“This is the table”_ - that’s not a “table”, that is simply an array. If all you need to make your request to the Twitter API is the user name, then you could simply loop over that array, get the necessary data, and then insert it back into the relevant element of the current record.